# Does $H=V(p) +x^2$ give a well-behaved Quantum Theory?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, path-integral, quantization

$V(p) $ is the Coulomb potential. I think this theory should be fine because Hamilton's equations are somewhat symmetric in $x$ and $p$. The momentum space Schrodinger equation will be:

$$i\frac{d\psi }{dt}=V(p) \psi +\frac{d^2}{dp^2}\psi$$

which is pretty much the same as the position space Schrodinger equation from standard quantum mechanics. The sign may lead to issues. But then, we could replace the Coulomb potential with its negative (which would be a different theory, but similar) .

**But** I'm not sure about the **path integral quantisation** of this. The Lagrangian will have some crazy dependence on $\dot x$, so I don't know how one would do that path integal. Maybe one could try this alternate Legendre transform to get an alternate principle of least action:

$$L(p, \dot p) =x\dot p -H$$

I think this will give a valid principle of least action because Hamilton's equations treat $x$ and $p$ symmetrically upto a sign. If the sign is somehow an issue, we could multiply both Hamilton's equations by $-1$. The new equations will give backward time dynamics of the same system.

Would this work? **Is this a valid quantum theory?** Then, is the condition of well-behaved quantisation that : dependence on least one of $x$ and $p$ should be quadratic and there are no higher than first order derivatives in the Lagrangian?